# Same order as datatable on X axis in Ms chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart, dundas

Data base send X-axis values 1,3,2,4,5 but when assigned to chart values are coming 1,2,3,4,5. How can show same order as table has on x -axis?

Datatable

```
X  Y
1  2000
3  1500
2  -500
4  -2000
```

Chart

```
X   Y
1   2000
2   -500
3   1500
4   -2000
```

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the "order by" in your SQL statement?

Comment: Post your code so we can see how you are binding to the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `DataBindXY`, instead use `DataBindY` so that the order of your data is maintained by your X axis.